# Asp.NET mvc data annotations validator kit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, validation

Can anyone suggest some good mvc validators kit avaliable to public for free.

I remeber I used one , in some of the projects , but I can't remeber it's name , and I'd like to ask you what you use.

Thanks.

Edit: I remember the kit I used had also client side validation support.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about [Data Annotations Extensions](http://dataannotationsextensions.org/). It is open source project that has following attributes with client side support for ASP.NET MVC:

- CreditCardAttribute
- CuitAttribute
- DateAttribute
- DigitsAttribute
- EmailAttribute
- EqualToAttribute
- FileExtensionsAttribute
- IntegerAttribute
- MaxAttribute
- MinAttribute
- NumericAttribute
- UrlAttribute
- YearAttribute

Answer (score 1):

FluentValidation for MVC is awesome, extensible and has support for far more complex validation scenarios that the other frameworks.

You can add it using NuGet, details available [on codeplex here](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the     System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

Comment: I am using this , simple there is a validation kit named foolproof , and there are a lot of good validators (Data Annotations) written there. (including client side validation implementation). I suggest to use it :)